# Phone veriication code is not working with firebase android

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to send phone verification code on my mobile through firebase phone authentication in android. but it is only working first time. when I am trying second time send verification code on same phone number then it is not working.

I have tried as follow code.

```
public class PhoneVerification extends AppCompatActivity {

    private String mVerificationId;
    FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    FirebaseUser firebaseUser;

    @BindView(R.id.editTextCode)
    EditText editTextCode;
    @BindView(R.id.btnSignIn)
    Button btnsignin;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_phone_verification);

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        firebaseUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
        ButterKnife.bind(this);
        //getting mobile number from the previous activity
        //and sending the verification code to the number
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String mobile = intent.getStringExtra("mobile");
        sendVerificationCode(mobile);

        btnsignin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String code = editTextCode.getText().toString().trim();
                if (code.isEmpty() || code.length() < 6) {
                    editTextCode.setError("Enter valid code");
                    editTextCode.requestFocus();
                    return;
                }

                //verifying the code entered manually
                verifyVerificationCode(code);
            }
        });

    }

    //the method is sending verification code
    //the country id is concatenated
    //you can take the country id as user input as well
    private void sendVerificationCode(String mobile) {
        PhoneAuthProvider.getInstance().verifyPhoneNumber(
                "+91" + mobile,
                60,
                TimeUnit.SECONDS,
                TaskExecutors.MAIN_THREAD,
                mCallbacks);
    }
}
```

If anyone have faced same issue and did it's solution then please share with me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Reduce the `TimeUnit.SECONDS` value. Once you received verification code then you will get again code after `60` seconds as you specified there. Simply reduce time 30 seconds you will get code again or do according your need.